# How do I increase the audio volume on a video

Tags: workflow

I have a .wmv file where the audio volume is too low.  I was able to edit two files into one and match the volume of two video files to the same volume using windows live movie maker, but not to increase the volume, the (edit as opposed to the playback) volume control is max'd out, I can go down in volume but not up.  Can Blender help me increase the playback volume of this video?

Comment: You really should use an external program for that, Blender is not really made to make an entire film, especially audio wise. A real audio producer uses a DAW and dozens of tracks, and only merges the audio into the video at the final exportation stage.

Comment: You may try some third party software like audacity, idealshare videogo etc simply search the above brand name and step by step to increase audio volume of video files.

Answer (score 5):

You can increase the volume in the strip properties (select the audio and press <kbd>N</kbd>)

[image]

You can even go past eleven all the way to 100.

Comment: Be sure to mention this feature to Nigel Tufnel, in case he needs that extra push over the cliff.

Comment: How should I approach this after I've already applied the sound crossover to some tracks?

Comment: nvm found it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1CjP2M7ZkE&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=20

Comment: If you increase the volume, the static, if any, will increase too. You could use a tool like Audacity to reduce the static.

Answer (score 2):

You can also control the master volume level, in "scene > audio" properties panel: by default is 1.0 but it allows up to 100.0

[image]